# Runtime error when inputting list using a for loop in Python 3

Tags: python, loops, runtime-error

I wrote this code for Cryptopangrams problem in google's codejam 2019,
this is the input I'm trying this code with and I keep getting runtime error when I submit on google codejam 2019, when I use other ide then I see that I have to press enter after the second input is given, the first input works just fine, I don't know how to skip this enter stage, I'm sure this is why i keep getting the runtime error.

**The problem can be found here:** https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051705/000000000008830b

[Here is the RE error, that's the only thing it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RveF.jpg)

[Proof that it works when testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo708.jpg)

INPUT (Please copy each line and enter it manually instead of copying the entire output as that wouldn't work with all the spaces in between lines):

2

103 31

217 1891 4819 2291 2987 3811 1739 2491 4717 445 65 1079 8383 5353 901 187 649 1003 697 3239 7663 291 123 779 1007 3551 1943 2117 1679 989 3053

10000 25

3292937 175597 18779 50429 375469 1651121 2102 3722 2376497 611683 489059 2328901 3150061 829981 421301 76409 38477 291931 730241 959821 1664197 3057407 4267589 4729181 5335543

I have no idea what to do.

CODE:

```
def decoder():
t = int(input())
for q in range(1,t+1):
    temp = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    l = temp[1]
    L = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    primes = []
    temp_list = []
    ans = ""

    temp_list.append(int(L[0]/gcd(L[0],L[1])))
    for i in range(1,l):
        a = gcd(L[i],L[i-1])
        temp_list.append(int(a))

    temp_list.append(int(L[l-1])/a)

    for i in temp_list:
        if i not in primes:
            primes.append(i)

    primes.sort()
    dic = {str(primes[i]): chr(i+65) for i in range(26)}

    print("Case "+"#"+str(q)+": ", end = "")
    for i in range(0,l+1):
        print(dic[str(temp_list[i])], end = "")
    print("")
```

def gcd(a, b):
    if (a == 0):
        return b
    return gcd(b%a,a)
decoder()

the expected result would be:

Case #1: CJQUIZKNOWBEVYOFDPFLUXALGORITHMS

Case #2: SUBDERMATOGLYPHICFJKNQVWXZ

Comment: t = int(input()) why do you int the input?? That's probably your error right there.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying, I have to make it an int because the range function in the next line in the for loop doesn't work unless the inputted t is an integer, also I'm getting the error only in Google code jam because I can't press enter there, In any other ide, I have to press enter when the second input is in.

Comment: _I keep getting runtime error_ Can you share the actual error with us?

Comment: Code jam doesn't tell you the error, it just says RE(runtime error)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Misinterpret the question, don't look at this.

`input()` takes in the entire string before the first newline. So for the first input, it is a number follow by a newline so there is no problem with that. But input `103 31` is taken literally as a string `"103 31"`. For this kind, you would need to read the entire string, then `split()` it into different substrings, then finally convert all of it to number.
For example:

```
>>> inputs = "1 2 3 4 5"
>>> # split the input
... x = input.split()
>>> # Convert list of strings into list of int
... x = [int(val) for val in x]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Comment: I have done the splitting for the second input as well, I'm not sure what you are talking about, can you tell me where exactly?

Comment: I actually misread the code. Now that I think about it this is a GCJ challenge, and the error could potentially be in the line `temp_list.append(int(L[0]/gcd(L[0],L[1])))` when the length of L is 1, can you make sure the problem statement has this list always bigger than 1?

Comment: Yes, 25 ≤ L ≤ 100.

Comment: And I should also mention that it works just fine when running tests, but i get RE when I submit it, I have no idea, what's going on.

Comment: I think it is a parenthesis issue, try this `temp_list.append(int(L[l-1]/a))` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still keep getting the same runtime error.

Comment: I have attached a link to the snapshot of the code working when testing it.